# How to consume URL with two '?' in retrofit

Tags: android, url, retrofit2

I am trying to use retrofit 2.3 in my Android App.

I have following url format :

> www.test.com/api?url=a?response=json.

How this URL will be casted to QueryParam? For first part www.test.com/api will be my base URL then `@Query("url")` value but how to handle `responsetype=json` after second `'?'`

Comment: i think format is: www.test.com/api?url=a&response=json

Comment: if it's not like @NguyễnTrungHiếu says, then `a?response=json` is value for `url` and should be urlEncoded? if server side expects this value and they do other parsing on it?! it's a very sligh possibility, mostly it's like what NguyễnTrungHiếu said.

Comment: www.test.com/api?url=a&response=json is not the format. URL has '?' instead of '&'

Answer (score 2):

it should be possible to also add this as query parameter

e.g.:

```
Call<TestSiteResult> getTestSiteInfo(@Query("url") String yourUrl, @Query("response") String responseType)
```

If this response parameter is needed always you can also consider using an OkHttpClient for the HTTP connection (you can simply add it with the client(OkHttpClient) method of the Retrofit.Builder) which is responsible for intercepting URLs and append a certain parameter to your URL (e.g. i used this for the interception of api keys).

A LoggingInterceptor could look like this:

```
public class TestLoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {

  @Override
  public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();
    HttpUrl originalHttpUrl = original.url();

    HttpUrl url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
        .addQueryParameter("response", "json")
        .build();

    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder();
        .url(url);

    Request request = requestBuilder.build;
    return chain.proceed(request);
  }
}
```

I hope this can help you.